# Cannot construct instance of Kotlin data class despite using jackson-module-kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a kotlin data class, but I get the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `TestBean` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"foo": "bar"}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1432)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1062)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1302)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1719)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1261)
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:13)
```

Here is the code :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
        .readerFor(TestBean::class.java)
        .readValue<TestBean>("{\"foo\": \"bar\"}");
}

data class TestBean(private val foo: String)
```

And the dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you please add data class which you are serializing/de-serializing it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the `private` property `foo`. You can either make it public or use `@JsonProperty` to make it work

```
data class TestBean(@JsonProperty("foo") private val foo: String)
```

Comment: That seems to fix it thanks but I don't understand why... If I do private fields in java it works... And I don't like either solutions (I don't want my bean fields to be public nor I want to specify every arg name)

Comment: works with java because compiler adds a default constructor if missing.

Comment: My field are final and I use lombok allargsconstructor only

Comment: I am assuming you also have getters, right?

Comment: I don't have getters, although I do have the jacksonized annotation indeed

Comment: But isn't jackson-kotlin-module supposed to help with that? I mean https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/jackson-kotlin says it is